# Why is my ion-select displaying the wrong label in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to display the label (`ion-label`) of my `ion-select/ion-option` to show "Activities Offered" instead of "Select date *". I have added another seperate ion-label for "Select date *" for my earlier ion-select/ion-option, but I am unsure of why it is showing that again instead of "Activities Offered".

Here are my codes for the "Activities Offered" + ion-select/ion-option:

```
<ion-label style="overflow:visible">
   Activities offered:<span style="color:red;">*</span>
</ion-label>
  <ion-select placeholder="Select an activity...">
     <ion-option *ngFor="let item of spaceActivityArr"> <-- Returns an array of ["Birthday", "Your own plans"]
       {{item.name}}
      </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Here is a photo of what is displayed from this ion-select:

[image]

My aim is to display "Activities Offered" instead of "Select date: *". Can anyone spot and issues with the codes?

Comment: Try to put them togethrr inside ion-item

Comment: @MostafaHarb Tried that, still the same result as above.

Comment: In the ts page add : customAlertOptions: any = { header: 'Activities or whatever...' }; And in the html page edit the select: <ion-select [selectOptions ]="customAlertOptions" placeholder="Select Activities..."> .if this gave you the answer tell me to post it as answer.

Comment: And if it didn't work also tell me since i think there could be another problem.

Comment: @MostafaHarb Just tried it, the result is the same as the image above.

Comment: Is there another select in the page? Since the * is coming from this select and merged with another element from above which is "select date:" so keep what i told you to do below and put the label and select in ion-item and remove from style from the label .